# Disccord.js message.content.includes creates an infinte loop

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
bot.on('message', async message => {
    if(message.content.includes('stuff')) {
        message.channel.send("*stuff*");
    }
}
```

So if someone says something with stuff on my server, the bot will infinitely message the chat with 
"repeat." I literally have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Is that the exact code it happens with? Sounds like the bot might just be acting on its own message again and again.

Comment: You have 1 `bot.on message` block?

Comment: As @0x464e mentioned. The bot is reading it's own messages. A simple 
`if (message.author.id === bot.user.id) return;` should do it.

Comment: @Antony that just returns false all the time.

Comment: Woops. I thought the bot was repeating the exact message. I see nothing wrong with the code. Other than the fact that you are missing an a closing parentheses next to the last curly brace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other commenters have mentioned, you're creating an infinite loop because you're checking your own bot's message too, which sends the same thing you're checking for. Ignoring the bot client or just all bots in general will work:

```js
bot.on('message', async message => {
    // To ignore your own client:
    if (message.author.id === bot.user.id) {
        return;
    }

    // To ignore all bots (including your own):
    if (message.author.bot) {
        return;
    }

    if(message.content.includes('stuff')) {
        message.channel.send("*stuff*");
    }
}
```